# Highlight text with TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Currently I have a textarea using TinyMCE: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/D2gaab

I want to highlight the text between the opening/closing braces. Does someone know if this is possible, and how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could consider inserting a `<mark>` tag, or another element with inline styling. Also, maybe only insert when the selection has any length.

```
 editor.addButton('spintax', {
  text: 'Spintax',
  icon: false,
  onclick: function () {
    editor.focus();
    if (editor.selection.getContent().length) {
        editor.selection.setContent("{<mark>" + editor.selection.getContent() + '</mark>}');
    }
  }
});
```

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/E2gaab